# Can "I couldn't hear what you just said" be disabled?

Tags: actions-on-google

Is there a developer control, either in api.ai, or at Actions on Google side, to disable the <"I couldn't hear what you just said" + Action repeat> behavior that occurs whenever user does not respond quickly enough after an utterance?

It can bodge some Actions; either those with carefully controlled language interactions, or those that perform "once only" functions as they speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement support for no-input handling. If you don't explicitly handle it, then either the API.AI agent will use its defaults or the assistant platform will provide defaults.

For API.AI, follow these instructions: https://developers.google.com/actions/apiai/fulfillment#no-input_reprompting

You can take a look at the Number Genie sample for prompts that will prompt the user to respond: https://github.com/actions-on-google/apiai-number-genie-nodejs

Comment: Thank you Leon for the great advice, and the pointer to the very instructive project, too.  Much appreciated.

Comment: One additional thought: inferring from your response, and after studying the documentation you referred me to, it seems like the answer to my original question, can "I couldn't hear what you just said" be disabled is no.  

As far as I can tell, we don't have a choice to have the assistant act like a person (that is, just be quiet until the user says something else).  We can't do anything purely within API.ai and Actions on Google settings.  And if we use external fulfillment, we can supply our own prompts.  

But in all cases there have to be prompts.  Did I get it right?

Answer (score 0):

For clarity, I'm summarizing Leon's advice and my own background research:

1. We cannot disable reprompting.  That is, we cannot design interactions in which an Action utterance is not followed immediately by a user utterance (i.e., where user silence is part of the conversation dynamic).
2. Through Fulfillment, we can provide alternate prompt form(s).
3. But we cannot disable or alter any of these system mechanisms: prompt after a few seconds of silence, if no reply repeat, after three tries quit the Action.